# Issues with installing node / running npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am not very skilled in Linux so bear with me...

I am trying to install Node.js using these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.18-1chl1~precise1
```

that are found here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

I ran these commands and after the last command I received this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I next tried running the command sudo apt-get install nodejs which gave me no errors.

However, when I run "npm install" it fails presenting this:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/sarah/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-30-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/sarah
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.8-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /home/sarah/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sarah/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you by chance already have NPM installed?  Have you considered just installing the binary tarball?

Comment: I don't even know that that is

Comment: I think you would be better off installing node through [https://github.com/creationix/nvm](nvm) instead from binaries.

Comment: @Sriharsha, I couldn't disagree more.  She doesn't need to go through the process of building it with that script.  Simply copying over the binaries would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Sarah, Instructions are here:  http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/07/node-v0-8-6-stable/  Get the URL of the latest package from here:  http://nodejs.org/download/  Basically, `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.19/node-v0.10.19-linux-x64.tar.gz ~/`, `mkdir ~/node`, `cd ~/node`, `tar zxvf ~/node-v0.10.19-linux-x64.tar.gz --strip=1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This command: `sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.18-1chl1~precise1` is just an ill-advised piece of documentation. Specifying the exact version number is a mistake in the common use case. So your use of just `sudo apt-get install nodejs` is the correct command and all should be well now.

After that it looks like you have both `node` and `npm` (they come together) successfully installed. Now you are trying to run `npm install`, which is normally run within a node module's directory and looks for a `package.json` file. Since your home directory is not a node module and doesn't contain a `package.json` file, you get an error.

Node is installed correctly and you are good to go. You can start developing a new module with `npm init` or you can clone an existing module from github for example, cd into that module's directory, and then run `npm install` and that should work.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to clone a module from github (I really know very little about Linux)... When I run npm init it asks for a git repository - since I am not uploading to github, do I need to specify something here?

Comment: no, npm init just writes out your package.json file, if you leave the git repo blank, it'll just be blank in your package.json.  You can update it later using a text editor if you change your mind about having a git repo.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the big picture (and thus what your next step is), but node & npm are OK. If you want to write a node script, write some code in `myscript.js` and then run it with `node myscript.js` and it will run.

Comment: I was very confused about this error when trying to go through the AngularJS tutorial.  You need to be in the project directory for the tutorial when you run 'npm install'.  This isn't clear.